# Wamp Is not working after reboot

Tags: windows-7, wamp, wampserver

I'm running win 7 x64, I just install a custopack theme among a few other things, rebooted and now when I run wamp, the icon stays orange

Port 80 is not used by anything. At least, skype has been set to use another plus it's not even running and wamp says port 80 is ok.

Other than that, I recently fiddled with vhosts and a few other things a few days ago. But the problem appeared right now after a reboot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't thank us, thank SuperUser.com

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I simple re-installed wamp. Random :S